# Fixed header and hide (scroll) address bar mobile browser with MDL framework?

Tags: mobile, browser, address-bar, material-design-lite

**Example template:** ANDROID.COM MDL SKIN - *getmdl.io/templates/android-dot-com/index.html*

**github:** [android.com sample](http://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/templates/android-dot-com)

This fixed-header on mobile. [Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dph0V.png)

How do I get the address bar hide (scrolls)? Number 2 in the screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal issue. Can't be fixed until Layout is completely refactored.

Ref: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1072

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem that the browser address bar would not auto-hide on mobile browsers (Chrome on Android) using an mdl-fixed layout.
I solved the problem adding my own stylesheet after the mdl-stylesheets in the header section of the .html file:

`<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mdl/material.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>`

In the styles.css file, I added:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 850px) {
  .mdl-layout__container {
    position: static;
  }
}

.mdl-layout__header{
  position: fixed;
}
```